# Pyspark check hdfs folder modify date

Tags: pyspark, hdfs

I am new for pyspark. Wondering from pyspark is there some function can get HDFS fold modify date?

Such as in HDFS:
[image]

In pyspark:

```
def get_user_folder_update_date():
    magic()
    return update_time

print get_user_folder_update_date()
2017-12-20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Filesystem API for getting modification time for the HDFS file or directory and then python time formating functions to get the date in expected format. For example:

```
import time
path = lambda p: spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(p)
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

time_ts = fs.getFileStatus(path('/tmp')).getModificationTime()
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", time.localtime(time_ts / 1000)))
```